# Hibernate: How to persist data in Composite Key where one Column has One to Many relation but other has not using IDClass?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, composite-key

Following is use case:

Composite Key Class

```
public class AgreementPeriodID implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "PERIODID")
    private String pid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "AGRID")
    private CustomerAgreement customerAgreement;

}
```

Many To One Class

```
@IdClass(AgreementPeriodID.class)
public class CustomerAgreementPeriod  implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "AGRID")
    private CustomerAgreement customerAgreement;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PERIODID")
    private String pid;
```

One to Many main class:

```
  public class CustomerAgreement implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerAgreement", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<CustomerAgreementPeriod> agreementPeriods;
```

Main Class:

```
 public static List<CustomerAgreement> ra() {
        List<CustomerAgreement> li = new ArrayList<CustomerAgreement>();
        CustomerAgreement cAgreement = new CustomerAgreement();
        cAgreement.setId(321212121l);
        cAgreement.setName("Harpreet");;
        cAgreement.setCustomerId("140");

        List<CustomerAgreementPeriod> cap = new ArrayList<>();
        CustomerAgreementPeriod capy = new CustomerAgreementPeriod();
        capy.setPid("1");
        capy.setValidFrom(new Date());
        capy.setValidTo(new Date());
        capy.setCustomerAgreement(cAgreement);

        CustomerAgreementPeriod capy2 = new CustomerAgreementPeriod();
        capy2.setPid("2");
        capy2.setValidFrom(new Date());
        capy2.setValidTo(new Date());
        capy2.setCustomerAgreement(cAgreement);

        cap.add(capy);
        cap.add(capy2);
        cAgreement.setAgreementPeriods(cap);
        li.add(cAgreement);


        CustomerAgreement cAgreement2 = new CustomerAgreement();
        cAgreement2.setId(321212122l);
        cAgreement2.setName("Harpreet");;
        cAgreement2.setCustomerId("140");

        List<CustomerAgreementPeriod> cap1 = new ArrayList<>();
        CustomerAgreementPeriod capy1 = new CustomerAgreementPeriod();
        capy1.setPid("1");
        capy1.setValidFrom(new Date());
        capy1.setValidTo(new Date());
        capy1.setCustomerAgreement(cAgreement2);

        CustomerAgreementPeriod capy23 = new CustomerAgreementPeriod();
        capy23.setPid("2");
        capy23.setValidFrom(new Date());
        capy23.setValidTo(new Date());
        capy23.setCustomerAgreement(cAgreement2);

        cap1.add(capy1);
        cap1.add(capy23);
        cAgreement2.setAgreementPeriods(cap1);
        li.add(cAgreement2);

        CustomerAgreement cAgreement3 = new CustomerAgreement();
        cAgreement3.setId(321212123l);
        cAgreement3.setName("Harpreet");;
        cAgreement3.setCustomerId("140");

        List<CustomerAgreementPeriod> cap12 = new ArrayList<>();
        CustomerAgreementPeriod capy12 = new CustomerAgreementPeriod();
        capy12.setPid("1");
        capy12.setValidFrom(new Date());
        capy12.setValidTo(new Date());
        capy12.setCustomerAgreement(cAgreement3);

        CustomerAgreementPeriod capy234 = new CustomerAgreementPeriod();
        capy234.setPid("2");
        capy234.setValidFrom(new Date());
        capy234.setValidTo(new Date());
        capy234.setCustomerAgreement(cAgreement3);

        cap12.add(capy12);
        cap12.add(capy234);
        cAgreement3.setAgreementPeriods(cap12);
        li.add(cAgreement3);
        return li;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("IntegratorMasterdataPU");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
//        CustomerAgreement cAgreement = em.find(CustomerAgreement.class, 32121212l);
//        em.getTransaction().begin();
//        em.remove(cAgreement);
//        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        for(CustomerAgreement ca: ra()) {

            em.persist(ca);

        }
        em.flush();


//        
    }
```

It shows all Insert statements but it does not persist data in database?
Am i missing with something?

Comment: Don't you need to commit the transaction? flush != commit.

Comment: @AlanHay: Correct